# How to remove object from arrayList using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arraylist

I have a arrayList which is pushing:

```
imageList.push({
    docId: docId,
    letterNo: letterNo,
    seqNo: seqNo
});
```

First the data pushed in my array is **docId:1 ,letterNo:1,seqNo:1** which is:

```
"{"docId":1,"letterNo":1,"seqNo":1}"
```

Another time the `New data` I send is **docId:2 ,letterNo:1,seqNo:1** which is :

```
 "{"docId":2,"letterNo":1,"seqNo":1}"
```

I want to compare all the old values of arrayList with new values and if all these three property matches,then I need to slice old object from arrayList. For example if i again send `"{"docId":1,"letterNo":1,"seqNo":1}"`,then old object should be poped out from arraylist,as it matches with old object and this current object needs to be pushed.So i tried:

```
imageList = imageList
    .filter(function (
        obj) {
        return (obj.docId !== docId && obj.letterNo !== letterNo && obj.seqNo !== seqNo);
    });
```

Though `docId` of two object 1 and 2  are different,it needs to be pushed,But it is just removing all object from arrayList,though all the three property are not matched.

Comment: yes yes sorry its array

Comment: Do you want to remove the old object from the array if it is similar to the new object?

Comment: yes @PrasanthGanesan but all thre property of object should matched

Comment: Array.splice might be helpful if you're removing something from array

Comment: Use `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: Actually his question is not about removing data from the array. What he is trying to do is, if there is similar data in the array then don't add the new data to the array (because there is already a similar data and it will add duplicate entry to array). Otherwise add the new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var newData = {
    "docId":2,
    "letterNo":1,
    "seqNo":1
};
//Solution using filters
var insertNewData = false;
var imageList = [{
    "docId":1,
    "letterNo":1,
    "seqNo":1
},
{
    "docId":2,
    "letterNo":1,
    "seqNo":1
},
{
    "docId":3,
    "letterNo":1,
    "seqNo":1
}];
imageList = imageList.filter(function(oldData){
    if(oldData["docId"] == newData["docId"] && oldData["letterNo"] == newData["letterNo"] && oldData["seqNo"] == newData["seqNo"])
    {
        insertNewData = true;//a flag
        return false;//remove old data from array
    }
    else
        return true;
});
if(insertNewData)
{
    imageList.push(newData);
    insertNewData = false;
    console.log("old data is removed and new data is pushed using filters",imageList);
}
```

In addition to this, I would like to provide some solutions which will prevent removing the items and again adding the removed items into the array. Because you don't need to remove old data if it is similar to new data. Instead, you need to tell your program not to store the new data if old data already exists.

```
//For searching objects in an array, convert objects into strings.
for(var i in imageList)
{
    imageList[i] = JSON.stringify(imageList[i]);
}

//Solution 1: Using Array.includes()
if(!imageList.includes(JSON.stringify(newData)))
    imageList.push(JSON.stringify(newData));

//Solution 2: Using Array.indexOf()
if(imageList.indexOf(JSON.stringify(newData)) == -1)
    imageList.push(JSON.stringify(newData));
```

Your filter did not work because
`return (obj.docId !== docId && obj.letterNo !== letterNo && obj.seqNo !== seqNo);` will return true. You need to return false if that condition is satisfied so that the old value will be filtered from your array.

Comment: Don't know about the link you sent. But mine works fine even in stack overflow complier

Comment: My solution works perfectly fine. Why did you downvote?

Comment: Can you be more specific? there are 4 if else

Comment: Thushar, I am trying to push duplicate data. That is why they are going in to the else part.

Answer (score 0):

this code will give you desired output...

```js
var imageList = [
  {
    docId: 1,
    letterNo: 1,
    seqNo: 1
  },
  {
    docId: 2,
    letterNo: 2,
    seqNo: 2
  },
  {
    docId: 3,
    letterNo: 3,
    seqNo: 3
  }
];

const someFunction = (imageList = [], docId, letterNo, seqNo) => {
  let newimageList = imageList
    .filter(image => {
      let newValues = [docId, letterNo, seqNo];
      let imageListvalues = [...Object.values(image)];
      return !(JSON.stringify(newValues) === JSON.stringify(imageListvalues));
    });
  
    newimageList.push({
      docId: docId,
      letterNo: letterNo,
      seqNo: seqNo
    });

  return newimageList;
};

var newimageList = []
newimageList = someFunction(imageList, 1, 1, 1);
newimageList = someFunction(newimageList, 1, 2, 1);

console.log(newimageList);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var imageList = [];

function checkPush(value) {
  imageList.map((val, index) => {
    if (
      value.docId == val.docId &&
      value.letterNo == val.letterNo &&
      value.seqNo == val.seqNo
    ) {
      imageList.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });
  imageList.push(value);
}
checkPush({ docId: 1, letterNo: 1, seqNo: 1 });
checkPush({ docId: 2, letterNo: 1, seqNo: 1 });
checkPush({ docId: 1, letterNo: 1, seqNo: 1 });
console.log(imageList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before adding the new data, you could check and remove the duplicated one using the following code:

```
function GetDuplicatedIndex(imageArray, newData) {
    return imageArray.findIndex(x => (x.docId == newData.docId && x.letterNo == newData.letterNo && x.seqNo == newData.seqNo));
}

var newData = {"docId":1,"letterNo":1,"seqNo":1}

// find the index of the duplicated data
var dupIndex = GetDuplicatedIndex(imageList, newData);

// remove the duplicated one if exists
if (dupIndex > -1) { imageList.splice(dupIndex, 1); }

// add new data
imageList.push(newData);
```